# The Names of Yehudis, Antiyochus or Yochanan Kohein Godol in the Torah

Tags: talmud-gemara, names, chanuka, purim

The *Gemara* in [*Chullin*](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.139b.11?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) 139b says the following:

> From where in the Torah can one find an
>   allusion to the hanging of Haman? He replied: The verse states after
>   Adam ate from the tree of knowledge: “Have you eaten of [hamin] the
>   tree, about which I commanded you that you should not eat?” (Genesis
>   3:11). Hamin is spelled in the same manner as Haman: Heh, mem, nun.

Yet, when it comes to Chanukah, why doesn't the *Gemara* ask: From where in the Torah can one find an allusion to Yehudis, Antiyochus or Yochanan Kohein Godol etc.?

[This question was asked by my rebbi Rabbi M. Fishberg]

Comment: Not just chanukkah, but you can actually expand your question to every famous person ever not involved with purim! (Thus this doesn't seem like such a compelling question. Can you explain why it you're interested in it or think there may be an interesting answer?)

Comment: Eisav married Yehudis

Comment: Probably because the essence of Purim is hester panim and hidden miracles, so we have to find the secrets.  For other things there's not such a big emphasis.  If anything, Chanukah is an open miracle, so finding it in the Torah is not such a big deal.  (Finding Yom Haatzmaut would be more interesting because the miracles there were more hidden, but of course the Gemara couldn't do that because it hadn't happened yet.)

Comment: What about medrash?